# NextJs 13 custom not-found.tsx not working when deployed to vercel

Tags: vercel, next.js13, custom-error-pages

I'm using NextJs 13 with the new not-found.tsx file.

Everything is working fine locally, but when I deploy the app to vercel, any 404 errors are just returning the standard **`404 | This page could not be found`**

The not-found.txs is the app/not-found.tsx.

I've tried .js as well, but get the same result.

I'm assuming this is something on Vercel, but despite searching, can't find anything to direct me.

Next Version: 13.4.8